# Combine Realm.io and Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, realm

I want to create Android application that can run while online and offline. It's possible to combine Realm.io for offline database and Firebase as Online service.

I'm trying to make simple application that directly add realm object to firebase, but i get error exception like this :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.Observable
at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:476)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType(Method.java:183)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:672)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:593)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:421)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.memberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:243)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addMethods(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:457)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collect(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:233)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:142)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:68)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:11)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.introspect(SerializationConfig.java:490)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:133)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:873)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:833)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:387)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:478)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:97)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2593)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542)
at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336)
at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:298)
at com.pringstudio.firebaserealm.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "rx.Observable" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-tubesock-0.0.12_19946b0113470caa2e5e499f498247824b9e76d9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.3.0_ce4b168a6a58bc3fcd41c2a9e083ac97b17599a0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.firebaserealm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.pringstudio.
```

Code

```
// Firebase Root
Firebase firebase = new Firebase("firebae_url");

Siswa siswa = new Siswa(
 Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString()),
 editTextNama.getText().toString()
);

Firebase refSiswa = firebase.child("siswa").child(String.valueOf(siswa.getId()));
refSiswa.setValue(siswa, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
 @Override
 public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
  if (firebaseError != null) {
   Log.e("Firebase Add", "Error: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal\n" + firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data tersimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 }
});
```

Object

```
package com.pringstudio.firebaserealm.model;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

/**
 * Created by sucipto on 5/18/16.
 */
public class Siswa extends RealmObject{

    private String nama;
    private int id;

    public Siswa(){};

    public Siswa(int id, String nama){
        this.id = id;
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }
}
```

When i not extends RealmObject firebase can accept it, but when i convert Siswa Object to extends realm object, it's cause error.

I want my object compatible with firebase and realm, any sugestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are using Jackson Databind, and that is what is causing the problem. There is a description of the problem and a work-around here:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind

But to also have the answer here:

This can be fixed by either adding RxJava to your project or create an empty dummy file that looks like the following.

```
package rx;

public class Observable {
    // Dummy class required for Jackson-Databind support if
    // RxJava is not a project dependency.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case RealmObject was attempted to update Firebase,but I got an error mentioning Firebase couldn't handle serialized objects. What I did instead was to clone the RealmObject, and in that way it was able to update from Realm to Firebase.

I started an application with Realm but realized the need to sync the data. So here is a quick solution

```
public void syncWithFirebase(){

DatabaseReference addresses = mRef.getDB().child(TESTABLE_ADDRESSES);
long numOfAddresses = mProvider.countAddresses();
ShortAddress address;

for( int i = 1; i <= numOfAddresses; i++ ){
    address = mProvider.getAddress( i );

    //we get a serialized error, so right now address is copied
    addresses
        .child( Long.toString(address.getAddressId()) )
        .setValue(AddressUtils.cloneAddress(address));
}
```

}

```
public void syncWithRealm( Response<Boolean> response){
DatabaseReference addresses = mRef.getDB().child(TESTABLE_ADDRESSES);


addresses.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for( DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
            ShortAddress address = snapshot.getValue(ShortAddress.class );
            mProvider.updateAddress( address );
        }

        response.onResult(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        response.onError( new Exception( databaseError.getMessage() ) );
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.Observable
```

If you see this exception in you java/android project with **Firebase** - easy solution for you:

> Your class imported to the firebase must be free ( don't extends from
>   other classes).

I work with **Realm** and **Firebase** in my android project - and for load data on both bases I created two identical classes.

for Realm:

```
public class Todo extends RealmObject {/*fields*/}
```

for Firebase:

```
public class TodoDTO {/*fields*/}
```

and copies from Todo to TodoDTO and back.